# Apply AWK on multiple files with pattern

Tags: awk, pipeline, paste

Suppose I have a folder with 9 files, labeled: X1.txt, X2.txt, X3.txt,Y1.txt, Y2.txt, Y3.txt,Z1.txt, Z2.txt, Z3.txt
For each triplet of files (X1, X2, X3), (Y1, Y2, Y3), (Z1, Z2, Z3) I need to merge them and then make AWK do (the same) action on it. Manually, I would need to write in the command line:

```
paste X1.txt X2.txt X3.txt | awk -f awkfile.awk
paste Y1.txt Y2.txt Y3.txt | awk -f awkfile.awk
paste Z1.txt Z2.txt Z3.txt | awk -f awkfile.awk
```

Since the above shows a clear pattern, I am wondering if there is a way to make this into a single command?

Comment: if you are looking for a way to generate these three commands, try `for f in X Y Z; do paste "$f"1.txt "$f"2.txt "$f"3.txt | awk -f awkfile.awk; done`

Comment: I don't know what you are aiming at ... but maybe: `for c in X Y Z; do paste "${c}"{1,2,3}".txt" | awk -f awkfile.awk; done`

Comment: "folder" is Windows terminology, in UNIX you probably mean "directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script does the job (I added comments to make every step clear).
The advantage is that this does not depend directly on the naming of the files, nor on the number of triplets. It only assumes that the directory only contains the files of interest and that they are sorted (which is the case for both in the question).

```
filelist=(path_to_directory/*) # record the (ordered) list of files into an array
for ((i=0; i<"${#filelist[@]}"; i+=3)); # loops from 0 to number of
                                        # files in increments of 3
do
   paste "${filelist[@]:i:3}" | awk -f awkfile.awk # paste 3 elements of the array, 
                                                   # with offset i and feed it to awk
done
```

Edit: The code is grayed out after the slash "/", but I do not know how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in X Y Z; do paste $i{1,2,3}.txt | awk -f awkfile.awk; done
```